How to address the performance impact of executing multiple functions dynamically compiled with Scala 2's runtime reflection?
I have an entity that generates Scala functions compiled dynamically using Scala 2's runtime reflection. My case is slightly more convoluted, but the following showcases the issue:
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Generator {
  val toolbox =
    reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()

  def generate(value: Long): Long => Long =
    toolbox.eval(q"(x: Long) => x + $value").asInstanceOf[Long => Long]
}

I have observed that evaluation performance degrades significantly the more compiled functions are being executed in sequence. For instance, the following JMH benchmark:
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import scala.util.Random

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
class BenchmarkGenerator {
  @Param(Array("1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000"))
  var nFunctions: String = _

  var evalF: List[Long => Long] = _

  @Setup
  def setup() =
    evalF = (0 until nFunctions.toInt).map(_ => Generator.generate(Random.nextLong(100000000L))).toList

  @Benchmark
  def evaluate() =
    evalF.foreach(_(1L))
}

Yields the following results in my machine:
Benchmark                    (nFunctions)  Mode  Cnt       Score        Error  Units
BenchmarkGenerator.evaluate             1  avgt    5       1.320 ±      0.020  ns/op
BenchmarkGenerator.evaluate            10  avgt    5      38.683 ±      0.249  ns/op
BenchmarkGenerator.evaluate           100  avgt    5     410.243 ±      4.137  ns/op
BenchmarkGenerator.evaluate          1000  avgt    5   14797.026 ±   1003.635  ns/op
BenchmarkGenerator.evaluate         10000  avgt    5  869938.386 ± 307011.008  ns/op

I was expecting a near-linear growth of the execution times, but that's not the case here.
I don't think this is related to the number of functions being compiled, since if I compile any number of functions but just repeatedly execute a single one I get the same execution times back. I suspect the compiled functions are being unloaded by the JVM, which makes things significantly slower the next time they need to be executed.
Is there a way to inspect what is going on and to address this issue (possibly by tuning the JVM)?

Are you sure generating functions at runtime using reflection is the best way to solve your meta-problem?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve my problem, but I'd still be interested in exploring the approach.

You have linear growth between 10 and 100 and it goes south somewhere after that. It could be even lack of memory and GC slowing things down.
